# Miro player doesn't recognize subtitle from video encoded by ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-subtitles

It was the first time I encoded a video on Ubuntu. I used `ffmpeg` to extract the video/audio, encode them and join with a subtitle to a new file.

All these steps were fine. I used the following command to mux these files.

```
$ ffmpeg -i [video_file] -i [audio_file] -i [sub_file] \
   -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text \
   -metadata:s:a language=eng \
   -metadata:s:s language:por \
   -sub_charenc UTF-8 [output_file]
```

However, Miro player doesn't recognize the subtitle. Even that, when I play other files with Miro, it finds the subtitles just fine. This makes me think that I'm possibly missing something in the above command.

Another strange thing is playing this new file with VLC and other players on Ubuntu/Windows, I can turn on the subtitles just fine.

Can anyone help me out with this?